# Django WeasyPrint - Export filtered list

Tags: django, pdf, django-filter, weasyprint

So I've created a pdf file from a ListView called "OrderListView". Now I would like to pass a queryset to the pdf file.

I rewrote my listview as a function view for more clarity. I need to find a way to pass the queryset to the pdf view. I'm using django-filter to create the filtered view. I have the following;

## filters.py

```
class OrderFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

class Meta:
    model = Order
    fields = {
        'start_date': ['gte'],
        'end_date': ['lte'],
    }
```

## views.py

```
from .filters import *

# View to show a filtered list using django-filter
def order_list(request):
    order_list = Order.objects.all()
    order_filter = OrderFilter(request.GET, queryset=order_list)

    start_date__gte = request.GET.get('start_date__gte','')
    start_date__lte = request.GET.get('start_date__lte','')

    return render(request, 'orders/order_list.html', {
        'filter': order_filter,
        'start_date__gte': start_date__gte,
        'start_date__lte': start_date__lte,
    })

# View to create a pdf file from the filtered view using WeasyPrint
def order_list_pdf(request):
    # Edited: Create queryset 
    start_date__gte = request.GET.get('start_date__gte','')
    start_date__lte = request.GET.get('start_date__lte','')

    order_list = Order.objects.filter(
        Q(start_date__gte=start_date__gte) |
        Q(start_date__lte=start_date__lte)
    )
    order_filter = OrderFilter(request.GET, queryset=order_list)

    response = HttpResponse(content_type="application/pdf")
    response['Content-Inline'] = 'attachment; filename=filtered_list.pdf'.format()

    html = render_to_string('pdf/pdf_booking_list_arrivals.html', {
        'filtered_list': order_list,
    })

    font_config = FontConfiguration()
    HTML(string=html).write_pdf(response, font_config=font_config)

    return response
```

So I have tried using

```
start_date__gte = request.GET.get('start_date__gte','')
start_date__lte = request.GET.get('start_date__lte','')
```

And pass the query with the url

```
#edited
<a class="btn" href="{% url 'order_list_pdf' %}?start_date__gte={{ start_date__gte }}&start_date__lte={{ start_date__lte }}">Create PDF</a>
```

This does create the query in the url but does not filter the list. The generated pdf is working, I just need to find a way to only send the filtered results to the pdf view.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The `href` is wrong, it should be `<a class="btn" href="{% url 'order_list_pdf' %}?q={{ query }}">Create PDF</a>`

Comment: Furthermore in your `order_list_pdf`, you do not seem to do anything with `q`: your `OrderFilter` only filters on `start_date` and `end_date`

Comment: Thanks for noticing. I just edited the url structure to take "start_date" and "end_date". The order_list_pdf is showing an unfiltered list though.

Comment: you probably should pass `start_date__gte` and `end_date__lte` as parameters to the template.

Comment: Just tried to create a queryset from the request.GET.get parameters. This should apply the queryset to the context but it doesn't seem to work. What am I missing?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks for the help! Found the issue. I used the wrong operator for the queryset! The bar "|" is replaced by "&". Works like a charm!

Comment: you do not need to use `&`, you can simply fiter with `.filter(start_date__gte=start_date__gte, end_date__lte=end_date__lte)`